# python - how do we add roles in discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have trouble adding roles to a user in discord, here's my code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
   if reaction.message_id == message_id_here:
        user = bot.get_user(reaction.user_id)
        await user.add_roles(name='Members')
```

here's the error:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things wrong with that code.

First off all object `user` represents Discord user (not tied to any guilds) while object `member` is tied to specific guild.

One user can be in multiple guilds and you will have `member` object of it per each guild. If you want data on guild you **need** the `member` object.

To add roles you need to call [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) on a [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object.

So instead of getting the `user` object get the `member` object by getting guild then getting member from it:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
    if reaction.message_id == message_id_here:
        guild = bot.get_guild(reaction.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(reaction.user_id)
        await member.add_roles(...)
```

Also note that [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) takes a role object, you cannot just pass `name='Members'`.

If you want to find that role from the guild then use [utils](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.find):

```py
    ...
    role = find(lambda r: r.name == 'Members', guild.roles)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Note that `find` is in `discord.utils.find`.